# Struggling to think Functionally in Racket

Tags: racket

I always have problems thinking functionally and here is a typical example.

```
(define tally_table (make-hash))

(define (process-each-line)
    (define actual_percent 5)
    (define new_record (list 0))
    (define add_record (list 1))
    (define (tally-records hash_value to-be-added)
      (map (lambda (number1 number2)
        (+ number1 number2)) hash_value to-be-added))
    (if (hash-has-key? tally_table actual_percent)
      (let* ([hash_value (hash-ref tally_table actual_percent)])
        hash-set! tally_table actual_percent (tally-records hash_value add_record)
      )
      (hash-set! tally_table actual_percent new_record)
    )
)
```

What I expected the code to do was add a new value to an empty hash table the first time run (which it does), then add to the hash table value on successive runs (which it doesn't - instead it returns a list of '(1) and the hash table value remains the same).
I'm guessing it might be to do with the scope of let*, but I'm certainly confused as to why the two sides of 'if' (appear to) behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a function call, but you missed parentheses around `hash-set!` in the "then" branch of `if`. Parentheses is the syntax for function call. Since you missed it, it doesn't perform function call.

To compare it with other languages like JS, instead of writing `f(x, y, z)`, you are (roughly) writing:

```
f;
x;
y;
return z;
```

In this case, it evaluates `hash-set!`, ..., `(tally-records hash_value add_record)`, and returns the evaluation result of `(tally-records hash_value add_record)`.

FYI, there's a function `hash-update!` which does both `hash-set!` and `hash-ref` at the same time, and it could also deal with when `hash-has-key?` returns `#f`, too. That means you don't need that `if` expression at all. You could just write this instead:

```
(hash-update! tally-table actual-percent
              (λ (current-value) (tally-records current-value add-record))
              new-record)
```

EDITED: with `hash-update!`, `tally-records` will be applied when `hash-has-key?` is `#f` too. You probably need to adjust the value of `new-record` to preserve the existing behavior. Alternatively, just use the regular `if` that you had before.

Comment: Thanks for that. I had parentheses around it initially but had run into other parenthesis issues with the let, so had removed them in an attempt to get it to compile! I had looked at hash-update! but couldn't work out what the difference between the two was.